# Split Git repository or keep two repositories of the same folder

Tags: git, github, repository

I use Git to track changes to a folder that contains all scripts and plugins for our project pipeline. So far so good. I'd like to share a subset of those files on GitHub. A subset, simply, because the complete repository also contains commercial plugins and other code which I cannot share publicly.

The scripts and plugins do sit intermingled in various folders. So it is not always as simple as sharing this folder and not that folder.

How would I go about doing this? It this possible at all?

EDIT:

Basically, my current structure is this:

```
programmA  
  |-plugins (both commercial and public)
  |-scripts (both commercial and public)  
programmB  
  |-plugins (both commercial and public)  
  |-scripts (both commercial and public)
```

In addition, the individual programs subfolders are structured according to this programs guidelines. I guess with a bit of housecleaning I could make something like this:

```
programmA  
  |-plugins commercial
  |-scripts commercial
  |-plugins public
  |-scripts public
programmB  
  |-plugins commercial
  |-scripts commercial
  |-plugins public
  |-scripts public
```

However, that still would not allow me to use modules, would it? Or would I need to use one module per program and subfolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you plan for this kind of thing from the start, you can keep 'public' branches for pushing to GitHub & 'private' branches that get merges from the public ones for your internal development.

Alternatively, you could set up the 'public' stuff as a sub module of the 'commercial' stuff.

Your problem here is a desire to do the reverse, create a public branch derived from private branches.  I suppose with enough cherry picking you may be able to create such a branch, but I don't envy you the effort.

Untested: Use Oleksandr's method to create the 1st commit of a 'public' branch in a new repository, then `fetch` in the private stuff.  Careful merging may produce a single repository with a 'public' branch with little history & a 'commercial' branch collection with a richer history.

---

Update: Sub-modules do require a directory boundry.  As such you can use them to partition Program A from Program B each as sub-modules of a larger project if this suits your needs.  If you can arrange your directories such that Public info is a sub-module (sub-directory) of the Private stuff, then this may work best for you.

Otherwise you may try the Public/Private branch approach.

Public branches will have only Public code in them or any of their parents.  Public branches will be the only ones you push to public repositories.

Private branches will contain both Public & Private information.  Work done in Public, can me merged into Private Branches but never the other way around.  Private branches will be pushed solely to Private repositories, where data from both Private branches and merged in Public branches will be visible.

If you think a feature may start out as Private & eventually become Public, you should base your new Private Feature Branch only on Public work, and then merge it into a Private branch.  This way when you do merge it into a Private branch, none of it's parent commits contain Private information. For this reason you may want to base each and every Private feature in it's own branch based on a Public branch, so that when/if you make them Public you need to do much less surgery on your repository to make the code in that branch Public.

Comment: I'm not really worried so much about the history at this point. It is all pretty stable. If I could start from scratch, how would you suggest I best proceed? Create a repo which is the commercial bit and then create a public module and copy all my public stuff in again? (Also, I have no clue how to do this yet, I am not very skilled with Git yet.)

Comment: Wait…a submodule resides in its own folder, correct? If so, that approach won't work, because I have both public and commercial stuff sitting in the same folder and there are several of these folders.

Comment: I made a change to the main question showing how my folder structure is laid out and why I see a problem with modules.

Comment: Haha, I think you just made my head explode tjd. :)
I will mark this as answered, but I can see that this will need some more Git studying before I can implement that confidently on my environment. Thanks anyway. At least you have shown me ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. Create local copy of the repository
2. Delete the .git folder in all subrepositories and repo itsetlf.
3. Do `git init` in the copy repo.
4. Add .gitignore file to the copy folder and specify the files you want to be omited by git.
5. `git add .` all the files in copy repo
6. Push the copy repository to github

You can find the default git ignores [here](https://github.com/skalinets/add-default-ignores) and modify them in accordance to your requirements.

You can also try to add the .gitignore file to your existing repo and commit changes, but i'm not sure that your scripts won't be inaccesible in older commits.

Comment: That would leave me with a second completely independent Git repo though, right? Two completely unrelated folders. So every time I make a change in my main repo, I'd have to copy it over to the GitHub repo by hand? That doesn't sound like fun.